# Programmatically create EditTexts based on Sudoku grid

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a Sudoku grid image loaded into my app, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting EditTexts to appear in each square. When I run the app, the numbers in the EditTexts are hardly visible. I've tried changing the background color and text color and nothing has changed.

```
/* PROGRAMATICALLY ADD EDITVIEWS via waiting for draw */
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
{

    public void onGlobalLayout() 
    {
        layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        /* not used yet
        int height = grid.getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = grid.getMeasuredWidth();
        int top = grid.getTop();
        //int bottom = grid.getBottom();
        int left = grid.getLeft();

        int square_height = height/9;
        int square_width = width/9;*/

         for ( int r = 0; r < 9; r++ )
         {
             for ( int c = 0; c < 9; c++ )
             {  
                 text_boxes[r][c] = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                 text_boxes[r][c].setId(r+c);
                 text_boxes[r][c].setText("1");
                 text_boxes[r][c].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                 text_boxes[r][c].setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)});
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                 params.setMargins(c*10, r*50, 0, 0);
                 layout.addView(text_boxes[r][c], params);
                 text_boxes[r][c].setBackgroundColor(0x0FF00);
             }
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't remove the listener when you are finished using it, so it can keep being called.

also, about the color of the EditText, you can change it to whatever you wish , by just changing the background of the EditTexts, or use a global style that sets a default background for EditTexts. you can even use [**this tool**](http://android-holo-colors.com/)